# DOMDocument - get script text from within body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, domdocument

What I am trying to do is get scripts from body tag but only scripts that have text not script links

eg. `<script type="text/javascript">console.log("for a test run");</script>`

not the scripts that have file src.

And I want to place those scripts to end of page before `</body>`.

So far I have

```
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "reaches 1 <br />";
        //work for inpage scripts
        $mainBody = @$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
        foreach (@$dom->getElementsByTagName('body') as $head) {
            echo "reaches 2";

            foreach (@$head->childNodes as $node) {

                echo "reaches 3";
                var_dump($node);
                if ($node instanceof DOMComment) {
                    if (preg_match('/<script/i', $node->nodeValue)){
                        $src = $node->nodeValue;
                        echo "its a node";
                        var_dump($node);
                    }
                }
                if ($node->nodeName == 'script' && $node->attributes->getNamedItem('type')->nodeValue == 'text/javascript') {
                    if (@$src = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue) {
                        // yay - $src was true, so we don't do anything here
                    } else {
                        $src = $node->nodeValue;
                    }
                    echo "its a node2";
                    var_dump($node);
                }
                if (isset($src)) {
                    $move = ($this->params->get('exclude')) ? true : false;
                    foreach ($omit as $omitit) {
                        if (preg_match($omitit, $src) == 1) {
                            $move = ($this->params->get('exclude')) ? false : true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($move)
                        $moveme[] = $node;
                    unset($src);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($moveme as $moveit) {
            echo "Moving";
            print_r($moveit);
            $mainBody->appendChild($moveit->cloneNode(true));
            if ($pretty) {
                $mainBody->appendChild($newline->cloneNode(false));
            }
            $moveit->parentNode->removeChild($moveit);
        }
$mainBody = $xhtml ? $dom->saveXML() : $dom->saveHTML();

        JResponse::setBody($sanitize?preg_replace($this->sanitizews['search'],$this->sanitizews['replace'],$mainBody):$mainBody);
```

### Update 1

The problem is `<script type="text/javascript">` can also be in div or can be in nested divs. So as using `foreach @$head->childNodes` only gets the top html tags and do not scan the inner tags that may contain `<script>` tags. I don't understand how to get all required script tags.

And there is no error but there also has no script tags on top nodes.

### Update 2

After an answer of xpath, thanks for the answer. There is some progress in task. But now after moving of scripts to footer, I can't delete/remove original script tags.

Here is the updated code I have so far:

```
        echo "<pre>3";
//        echo "reaches 1 <br />";
        //work for inpage scripts
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $script_tags = $xpath->query('//body//script[not(@src)]');

        foreach ($script_tags as $tag) {
//            var_dump($tag->nodeValue);
            $moveme[] = $tag;
        }
        $mainBody = @$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
        foreach ($moveme as $moveItScript) {

            print_r($moveItScript->cloneNode(true));
            $mainBody->appendChild($moveItScript->cloneNode(true));
//            var_dump($moveItScript->parentNode);
//            $moveItScript->parentNode->removeChild($moveItScript);
/*            try{
                $mainBody->appendChild($moveit->cloneNode(true));
                if ($pretty) {
                    $body->appendChild($newline->cloneNode(false));
                }
                $moveit->parentNode->removeChild($moveit);
            }catch (Exception $ex){
                var_dump($ex);
            }*/
        }
        echo "</pre>";
```

### Update 3

I was working for Joomla, was trying to move scripts to footer of the page. I had used the scriptsdown plugin, which moved the scripts from head tag to bottom. but the scripts with in the mid page were not moved to the bottom, so that what was causing the inpage scripts to not respond properly.

My problem is now solved. Posting my solution code so if it might help someone in future.

```
function onAfterRender() {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        /* test that the page is not administrator && test that the document is HTML output */
        if ($app->isAdmin() || $doc->getType() != 'html')
            return;
        $pretty = (int)$this->params->get('pretty', 0);
        $stripcomments = (int)$this->params->get('stripcomments', 0);
        $sanitize = (int)$this->params->get('sanitize',0);
        $debug = (int)$app->getCfg('debug',0);
        if($debug) $pretty = true;
        $omit = array();
        /* now we know this is a frontend page and it is html - begin processing */
        /* first - prepare the omit array */

        if (strlen(trim($this->params->get('omit'))) > 0) {
            foreach (explode("\n", $this->params->get('omit')) as $omitme) {
                $omit[] = '/' . str_replace(array('/', '\''), array('\/', '\\\''), trim($omitme)) . '/i';
            }
            unset($omitme);
        }
        $moveme = array();
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->recover = true;
        $dom->substituteEntities = true;
        if ($pretty) {
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
        } else {
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        }
        $source = JResponse::getBody();
        /* DOMDocument can get quite vocal when malformed HTML/XHTML is loaded.
         * First we grab the current level, and set the error reporting level
         * to zero, afterwards, we return it to the original value.  This trickery
         * is used to keep the logs clear of DOMDocument protests while loading the source.
         * I promise to set the level back as soon as I'm done loading source...
         */
        if(!$debug) $erlevel = error_reporting(0);
        $xhtml = (preg_match('/XHTML/', $source)) ? true : false;
        switch ($xhtml) {
            case true:
                $dom->loadXML($source);
                break;
            case false:
                $dom->loadHTML($source);
                break;
        }
        if(!$debug) error_reporting($erlevel); /* You see, error_reporting is back to normal - just like I promised */

        if ($pretty) {
            $newline = $dom->createTextNode("\n");
        }

        if($sanitize && !$debug && !$pretty) {
            $this->_sanitizeCSS($dom->getElementsByTagName('style'));
        }

        if ($stripcomments && !$debug) {
            $comments = $this->_domComments($dom);
            foreach ($comments as $node)
                if (!preg_match('/\[endif]/i', $node->nodeValue)) // we don't remove IE conditionals
                    if ($node->parentNode->nodeName != 'script') // we also don't remove comments in javascript because some developers write JS inside of a comment
                        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
        $body = @$dom->getElementsByTagName('footer')->item(0);
        foreach (@$dom->getElementsByTagName('head') as $head) {
            foreach (@$head->childNodes as $node) {
                if ($node instanceof DOMComment) {
                    if (preg_match('/<script/i', $node->nodeValue))
                        $src = $node->nodeValue;
                }
                if ($node->nodeName == 'script' && $node->attributes->getNamedItem('type')->nodeValue == 'text/javascript') {
                    if (@$src = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue) {
                        // yay - $src was true, so we don't do anything here
                    } else {
                        $src = $node->nodeValue;
                    }
                }
                if (isset($src)) {
                    $move = ($this->params->get('exclude')) ? true : false;
                    foreach ($omit as $omitit) {
                        if (preg_match($omitit, $src) == 1) {
                            $move = ($this->params->get('exclude')) ? false : true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($move)
                        $moveme[] = $node;
                    unset($src);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($moveme as $moveit) {
            $body->appendChild($moveit->cloneNode(true));
            if ($pretty) {
                $body->appendChild($newline->cloneNode(false));
            }
            $moveit->parentNode->removeChild($moveit);
        }

        //work for inpage scripts
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $script_tags = $xpath->query('//body//script[not(@src)]');

        $mainBody = @$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
        foreach ($script_tags as $tag) {
            $mainBody->appendChild($tag->cloneNode(true));
            $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
        }

        $body = $xhtml ? $dom->saveXML() : $dom->saveHTML();
        JResponse::setBody($sanitize?preg_replace($this->sanitizews['search'],$this->sanitizews['replace'],$body):$body);
    }
```

Comment: so whats happening here? where's the error? its just a chunk of code

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte
i updated my question. actually my code can not find script tags in page under body tag.

Comment: either just use xpath just like below, or simply just `$mainBody->getElementsByTagName('*')`, i'd prefer the xpath route though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get ONLY the `<script>` nodes that dont have the `src` attribute you better use the `DOMXPath`:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$script_tags = $xpath->query('//body//script[not(@src)]');
```

The variable `$script_tags` is now a `DOMNodeList` object that contains all of your script tags.
You can now loop over the `DOMNodeList` to get all the nodes and do whatever you would like to do with them:

```
foreach ($script_tags as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag->nodeValue);
    $moveme[] = $tag;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. but how to remove the original script tags.
I tried use foreach on `$moveme[]` and tried to remove there `$moveit->parentNode->removeChild($moveit);` but this dosen't seem to help.

Comment: i also want to mention your code helped me but still the job is incomplete.

Comment: i updated my question with your code. please tell how to delete the original script node after cloning the nodes to bottom of page.

Comment: Thankyou sir. there was issue on my end but your code helped me alot. 
Many Thanks.